# Применение глаголов "нарезать" и "порезать"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Глаголы "нарезать" и "порезать".  В каких случаях и к каким действиям применимы?

Comment: нарезать колбасы, порезать палец

Answer (score 2):

Нарезать-

1. разделить на части: Нарезать сало, нарезать хлеба;
2. сделать нарезку: Нарезать винт;
3. размежевать: Нарезать новые участки под дачи;
4. наготовить, срезая или убивая: Нарезать веток. Нарезать кур, уток.
5. в разговорном стиле о прохождении какого-то расстояния (на коньках, лыжах): Я уже километров 20 нарезал. Он уж кругов 30 нарезал.

Порезать -

1. поранить чем-то режущим: Порезать руку;
2. нарезать в каком-то количестве: Порезать хлеба (разг.); зарезать в каком-нибудь количестве: У меня уток порезали. Всю птицу порезали.